GRPC Bidirectional Streaming Issue - Request Stream keeps getting closed
I've been suffering implementing grpc bidirectional stream.
I'm expecting the server keeps request stream open until there's an explicit stream dispose... though for some reasons, my server keeps getting an exception{"Can't read messages after the request is complete."}. If you see my code below, client is sending 1000 requests but server's requestStream.ReadAllAsync() throws an exception after a few iterations which don't make sense to me.
Thanks for the help!
This is my server side implementation of bidirectional stream
        private async Task HandleUpdate(IAsyncStreamReader<UpdateRequest> requestStream,
            IServerStreamWriter<UpdateResponse> responseStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            async Task ProcessRequests()
            {
                try
                {
                    await foreach (var request in requestStream.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Update: {request}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

            async Task PublishResponses()
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // WIll add publish function
                        await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
                    }

                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAny(ProcessRequests(), PublishResponses());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception");
            }
        }


And this is a client
using (var call = client.StreamTableUpdate())
{

   try
   {
      // Writing to the request stream
      var writeTask = Task.Run(async () =>
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
         {
            try
            {
               var request = new UpdateRequest();
               await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               // Log the exception here...
            }
         }

         await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
      });

      await foreach (var response in call.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
      {
         // To DO
      }
      await writeTask;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      _logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred while processing the stream.");
   }
}


